# Checking whther the integral $\int_1^∞ \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{x}+1}} dx$ convergent

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need to check convergence of $\int_1^∞ \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{x}+1}} dx$ .
I think it divergence cause it bigger than $\int_1^∞ \frac{1}{x} dx$ but I can't prove it. I have an hint that $\lim\limits_{x \to ∞} $$ x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is 1 but I cant decipher how it useful. any help? THANKS

Comment: Say we have an integral $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $f(x)$ is strictly positive for $x \in [a,\infty]$. Can the integral converge if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: You mean that because $\lim\limits_{x \to ∞}f(x)=1 $ so the integral is necessarily divergent? Its a theorem? THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$\frac1{x^{\frac1x+1}}\sim_\infty \frac1x$$
which means that: for $\epsilon>0$ there is $A>0$ such that for $x\ge A$ we have
$$\frac1{x^{\frac1x+1}}\ge (1-\epsilon)\frac1x$$

From this inequality we conclude that the given integral is divergent since
$$\int_A^\infty\frac{dx}{x}=+\infty$$